# Does Blazor support something like AngularJS' attribute directives?

Tags: blazor

In AngularJS one can create attribute directives that can be reused in different views.

As a simple example:

```
<span makeRed>
    This is some text
</span>
```

makeRed is an attribute directive that turns any element's text to red.

Can Blazor do something similar as a reusable piece of code and plugged in an html element in some fashion? How?

**Update:**
Maybe it's not called directive in Blazor so don't get hang up on this word. The goal of what an attribute directive does in AngularJS is what I am looking for in Blazor. Whatever way Blazor does it.

Comment: Did you find an answer about this one? I'm also looking for something similar but I did not find one yet.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5607) helps, it seems that you can achieve the desired results with the new [DynamicComponent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like:

```
<span style="@makeRed" >I have no style</span>

<RecipeSelector @bind-IsOpen="@dialogIsOpen"  @bind-Value="@recipe"></RecipeSelector>

@code
{
    private string makeRed = "background: red; color: yellow;";
}
```

`makeRed` can either be a fixed string, or a function that runs some logic to decide if it's red or now `MakeRedIfNotLoggedIn()`, etc.. You can also do the same thing with CSS classes, applying special classes to controls.

You can have a "global" class that has all your definitions.

HTH

Comment: AngularJS directives are very powerful. My color example wasn't a good example it seems because people are posting answers (deleted) about how to make text red dynamically in Blazor. That's not the point of my question. Attribute directives in Angular can do a lot more. Custom validations. They have access to other elements in the same scope. ..etc.